# WCF message routing debugging error - Multiple headers

Tags: wcf, debugging, router

I'm trying to understand WCF message routing, so I'm trying to recreate a sample passthrough router that I found in order to understand the pieces. The problem is that when I run mine in the debugger, I get the exception:

Multiple headers with name 'VsDebuggerCausalityData' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink' found.

I've read that this is because I'm debugging all the pieces at the same time, and that the debugger is adding this data on each hop? However, I can debug all the pieces in the original sample I'm working from with no errors, so I'm not sure I believe the explanation I've seen, or I don't understand something yet. Anyone have an explanation how I can debug mine without getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your machine config has  element. You might need to comment this out. (Before any changes to machine config do **back it up**)